# Assign partial factor levels in R

Tags: r

I want to assign factor levels but I'm not always going to know all of the values so I want to make sure that only a few factors are at the beginning if they are present. Example would be I want strawberries to be factor level 1 and kiwis be factor level 2 and all the rest get assigned alphabetically

```
data <- data.frame(
  
  parameter = c(rep("apple",3), rep("banana", 3), rep("strawberry", 3), rep("kiwi", 3)),
  date = c(rep(c(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-02'), as.Date('2021-01-03')), 4)),
  value = c(0,2,3,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0)
)
```

If I were to order by parameter it would go strawberry, kiwi, apple, then banana. Unfortunately I won't always know what the other factors may be. Sometimes it may be apple and banana, or it could be apple, bananas, and pears. The possibilities are endless.

If you need extra context, a user will upload a csv to a shiny app with the 3 columns but the parameters could be different for ever user. If strawberry and kiwi are present in the parameters they need to be assigned a factor level first and all other factors assigned alphabetically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to change the `order` in `levels` of `factor`

```
v1 <- c('strawberry', 'kiwi')
data$parameter <- with(data, droplevels(factor(parameter,
          levels = c(v1, sort(setdiff(parameter, v1))))))

levels(data$parameter)
#[1] "strawberry" "kiwi"       "apple"      "banana"
```

NOTE: It may be better to wrap with `droplevels` (in case the 'strawberry' or 'kiwi' is not present in the data).

The above code may look perplexing.  The logic is

- `setdiff` - returns the unique elements of the column without the values in 'v1'
- `sort`- the elements (in default alphabetic order)
- `c` - concatenate the 'v1' elements at the start in the `vector`
- `levels`- specify the unique `sort`ed vector as `levels` argument in `factor`
- assign the `factor` to the original column
- `droplevels` - remove unused levels in case the elements in 'v1' are not present

---

Or another option is `fct_relevel`

```
library(forcats)
data$parameter <- fct_relevel(data$parameter, v1)
```

---

If we need to use `tidyverse`, just copy the code within the `with` and specify it in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
         mutate(parameter = droplevels(factor(parameter,
          levels = c(v1, sort(setdiff(parameter, v1))))))
```

Comment: Just tested set diff on the real data. Works great! The drop levels is necessary in my case. Is there any way to to implement either option into a dplyr mutate string?

Comment: @MelissaSalazar i updated with a `dplyr` option